# MongoDB Mapredure function with RockMongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm using RockMongo to test a mapReduce function but I encountered some problem. I even used a very simple query to test it, but it failed again with the same error :

Here is the command generated by RockMongo (I use the mapReduce plugin) :

```
{
   mapreduce : "TEST__CHFUSD",
  map : function () {
     emit(this.ts,
     this.1_bid); 
  },
   reduce : function (key,
   values) {
     return Array.sum(values); 
  },
   out : {
    "map_reduce_test1"
  },
   keeptemp:false,
   jsMode : false,
   verbose : false 
}
```

here is a document example :

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("533d54aa72b378fd77b85f7b"),
   "ts": ISODate("2014-04-03T12: 31: 38.461Z"),
   "1_bid": 7.32421,
   "1_bidQty": 3000000,
   "1_bidts": ISODate("2014-04-03T12: 31: 38.460Z"),
   "1_bidown": "LP1",
}
```

And the error returned :

```
{
   "errmsg": "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {",
   "code": NumberInt(16722),
   "ok": 0 
}
```

So it seems that there is a bracket missing or in excess, I tried to remove the brackets around the out value but the same error was fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some problem with "out".

Value of "out" which is `{"map_reduce_test1"}` is not a valid document. I think that's what causing the problem.

Comment: I changed it into  out : "map_reduce_test1", it worked, but now I have this error : Response from server:
{
   "errmsg": "exception: not code",
   "code": NumberInt(10062),
   "ok": 0 
}

Comment: Sorry mann no idea about this. I just checked syntex in your code. May be this link can help you out. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Ts4zPiTkAKo

Comment: Yes, I already looked at it, but it didn't helped. It' seems that it's a lake of feature with rockmongo, because it works well in the shell. But thanks.